# Sphinx: URL to link directly to a label, from outside Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I have a Sphinx project with several pages, each with several sections. I label the sections as so, for example in `my_page.rst`:

```
.. _sec_foo:

Foo
~~~
```

I can link to these sections from within my Sphinx docs, for instance with

```
:any:`sec_foo`
```

I'd like to be able to provide a link, from elsewhere on the web, to my "Foo" section that doesn't depend on knowing that it's in `my_page.rst`.

I imagine something like https://myproject.org/en/latest/labels/sec_foo which redirects to the link above, but any solution that lets me move `.. _sec_foo:` from one page to another, without changing my links elsewhere, is acceptable.

Is there a way to achieve this using standard Sphinx functionality? If not, with a plugin? If not, using some features of Sphinx to make the do-it-yourself approach (e.g. parse source to get all label/page pairs, generate pages for all URLs with redirects) less painful?

Comment: The only option would require the external site to also use Sphinx. That option would be the [intersphinx plugin](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html#module-sphinx.ext.intersphinx).